# Increase vertical space between lines in rdlc

Tags: c#, rdlc

I need to know how, if has any way, to increase vertical space between lines.
I tried to draw an image in rdlc, but I had prefer just increase the space without it.

Comment: try by using the ASCII code Chr(32) instead of a space. For example: =Chr(32) & Chr(32) & Chr(32) & Chr(32) & your_text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this out of the box.

As a workaround I've used empty placeholders inside the text box to control the spacing. (if you need more space, increase font size).